# RabbitMq like topic exchanges with Masstransit

Tags: c#, message-queue, masstransit, rabbitmq-exchange

I read the rabbitmq tutorials and really liked the Idea of [topic exchanges](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-dotnet.html). In my architecture I would have topics like `continent.city.street`. Where, as you can imagine, there are only a limited number of continents, but nearly infinite cities & streets, which both can have duplicated names (like `NorthAmerica.GeorgsTown.Mainstreet`, `Europe.GeorgsTown.Mainstreet`, `Asia.NewTown.Mainstreet` and `Australia.NewTown.LostRoad`)

Now I learned that [Masstransit](https://masstransit-project.com/), a Libary I want to learn/use, [does not support this kind of topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147212/publish-message-using-exchange-and-routing-key-using-masstransit). (There are somehow supported but then I also could use a generic RabbitMq client)

So what is the best way to achieve a **similar** thing, as with rabbitmqs topic exchanges, but with Masstransit (over (any) MQ/[rider](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/riders/) system), **in regards of performance**?

Some facts which could make the difference regarding performance:

- Nearly no consumer is interested in a whole continent - but some are. `Asia.*.*`
- *Continents primary goal is to make cities unique (in this fictional case).*
- About ~30% of the consumers would like to subscribe to cities regardless
  of continent or street. `*.GeorgsTown.*`
- About ~30% of the consumers would like to
  know what happens on specific streets regardless the city or continent. `*.*.Mainstreet`
- About ~30% is watching for specific combinations like `Antarctica.GeorgsTown.Mainstreet`

Answer (score 0):

MassTransit supports topic exchanges just fine, they're similar to those defined in the [Direct Exchange](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Direct) sample, but using a topic pattern routing key instead.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I tested it correctly - the filtering is done on the client side? However I only found the `x.UseRoutingKeyFormatter()`

Comment: The filtering is done by RabbitMQ when using topic exchanges. The routing key formatter is just to set the routing key automatically when sending/publishing messages. You can also set it explicitly when sending/publishing a message.

Comment: The created exchange is of type `fanout` when I use the RoutingKeyFormater with the given topic syntax. It only gets change to topic if I use `cfg.Publish<T>(x => { x.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Topic; });`. Is this the correct solution (combining both commands)?

Comment: Yes, you'd need to configure the exchange for every message type.