# costum messege consumption in MassTransit

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have a requirement where i have two ASP Net Core applications (A and B) that have the same code base. Each applications publishes Some Commands that it consumes and handel. Now, when Application A publishes a message, it is been consumed by both A and B as they both have the same consumers and same Message types. Am trying to achive the behavior where when application A publishes a message, the message should only be consumed by A and not by B.

I was wondering if it's possible to use the prefix used in

`x.SetEndpointNameFormatter(new KebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter(prefix: "ApplicationA", includeNamespace: false));`

Because each of A and B have a different prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood right, you are using masstransit with rabbitmq, maybe you can solve your requirement by configuring the exchangetype to direct exchange type.

```
cfg.send<testmessage>(x => { x.useroutingkeyformatter(context => "routingkey"); });
cfg.message<testmessage>(x => x.setentityname("testmessage"));
cfg.publish<testmessage>(x => { x.exchangetype = exchangetype.direct; });
cfg.receiveendpoint(host, "testmessage_queue", e =>
{
    e.bindmessageexchanges = false;
    e.consumer<updatecustomerconsumer>();
    e.bind("testmessage", x =>
    {
        x.exchangetype = exchangetype.direct;
        x.routingkey = "routingkey";
    });
});
```

by using different routingkey for project A and project B your can consume the message accordingly in reuired projects.

[Code copied from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53696155/)